# Why doesn't VS Code add brackets after autocompleting "print"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

In pycharm, I can just type "pri", press enter and "print()" appears, but in VS Code, only "print" comes. How can I make the brackets after "print" also appear automatically?

Secondly, such things aren't completed such as in PyCharm.

Is there any solution for this problem or should I continue with this inconvenience?

I've turned on auto closing bracket.

Comment: Make sure you've configured VS Code for Python 3.x syntax.